# Python merge items from two list

Tags: python, string, list, merge

I have the following codes:

```
    for j in range(4):
      print md_array[j:j+1]
    for j in range(4):  
      print y_array[j:j+1]
    for j in range(4):
      print md_array[j:j+1]+y_array[j:j+1]
    for j in range(4):
      print "%s%s" % (md_array[j:j+1], y_array[j:j+1])
```

The results are:

```
['12/1/']['12/2/']['12/3/']['12/34/']
['2011']['2010']['2009']['2008']
['12/1/', '2011']['12/2/', '2010']['12/3/', '2009']['12/34/', '2008']
['12/1/']['2011']['12/2/']['2010']['12/3/']['2009']['12/34/']['2008']
```

BUT actually I want to output

```
    ['12/1/2011']['12/2/2010']['12/3/2009']['12/34/2008']
```

I tried append but failed...So what's wrong with my codes??

Comment: why are you using slices (var[i:i+1]) instead of `var[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

`array[start_index:end_index]` gives you a slice, a sub-list of the list it's applied on. In this case, you want to get a single item. Try the following code:

```
for j in range(4):
    print "%s%s" % (md_array[j], y_array[j])
```

You can read more about slicing and indexes on [documentation for lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 1):

```
print "".join("[%s%s]"%t for t in zip(md_array, y_array))
```