# How can I merge members of a list in python?

Tags: python

CURRENT output:

```
['test1.txt StatusCode: 123', 'test2.txt StatusCode: 726', 'test1.txt CompanyID: abc']
```

DESIRED output:

```
['test1.txt StatusCode: 123 CompanyID: abc', 'test2.txt StatusCode: 726']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python merge items from two list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651080/python-merge-items-from-two-list)

Comment: I have just a single list, not 2 lists. but I will give it a try. thanks

Comment: Why do you want that as your output? It seems like a string is precisely the wrong structure for your data, and will make any subsequent operation many times more difficult that it needs to be.

Comment: The full picture looks like this. [1] find two files (done); [2] find some strings within those files (done); [3] attach found strings to each file. e.g. file1.txt - strings: 'test1' and 'test2' + file2.txt - strings: 'test1'. I want to create a list having: ['file1.txt test1 test2', 'file2.txt test1'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code. It works for your sample.

```
current_output = ['test1.txt StatusCode: 123', 'test2.txt StatusCode: 726', 'test1.txt CompanyID: abc']
d = dict()
order = []
for item in current_output:
    k,v = item.split(' ', 1)
    if k not in order:
        order.append(k)
    d[k] = d.get(k, []) + [v]
desired_output = ["%s %s" % (k, ' '.join(d[k])) for k in order]
print desired_output
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get the last elem of the list, split it and then append this to the others string elems